# Rails: How to find records with the condition inside the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am using rails 3.2 and I want to make this more dynamic. I want to show only active jobs (depending on the dates they were created at)

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
    scope :is_active, lambda { where("created_at >= DATE(?)", 30.days.ago) }
end
```

I want to be able to add a column to my type table with the number and base the query on it.

I added my column and I'm looking for something like this

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :type
    scope :is_active, lambda { where("created_at >= DATE(?)", type.numberofdays) }
end
```

I'm not sure what to look for, I've read the documentation on active records. Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: I think you need to describe a little more what's not working. Are you getting an error, are the records not the right ones?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can use `DATE()` on just a single integer value.  What database are you using?  To find all the `Jobs` that fall within the past `type.numberofdays`, you can use the following which has the updated scope.

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :type
    scope :is_active, lambda { joins(:type).where("created_at >= :newer_than_date", newer_than_date: Date.today - type.numberofdays) }
end
```

**Update:** `active_by_type`:

```
scope :active_by_type, lambda { |type| joins(:type).where("created_at >= :newer_than_date", newer_than_date: Date.today - type.numberofdays) }
```

Comment: You are right, in my original example I was using that
    scope :is_active, lambda { where("created_at >= DATE(?)", Rails.application.config.number_of_days_for_inactive.days.ago) }

With your code I'm getting undefined local variable or method `type' for #<Class:0x5aa0380>

Comment: You are right, the `type` is going to be undefined.  And since this is a `scope`, I think the better approach would be to pass in `type` for your `Job` as shown in the update above.  What do you think?

Comment: thanks for answering that quickly. Can you exlpain your update so I could understand better? Thank you

Comment: So with the update what you will be doing is `Job.active_by_type(type)` where `type` is an instance of `Type`.  Does this make sense?

Comment: I am always displaying all the jobs except the one where the expired date is reached. How would I know the current type before querying?

Comment: `type = Type.find(...)` then `Job.active_by_type(type)`.  If you don't want to do this then you are going to have to use DB specific `date` functions which would be passed in that `where` method.